# Highcharts Stacked area charts

Tags: highcharts, stacked-area-chart

I want to have a stacked area chart with missing data points having x-axis as date time and y-axis as products quantity. How can I achieve this?
I have tried using line chart and area chart but it is not solving the purpose.

Comment: Hi @Akshay, What do you exactly want to achieve? Here: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/j5hzu4wd/ you can find a basic area chart with all your requirements.

Comment: add the code snippet so we can understand better about the problem